# Shortcut comment next to tags in BBedit

Tags: sublime-text-2, comments, bbedit

In Sublime Text 2 I can create a comment next to a tag by using shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> which results in something like this:

```
<a href=""></a><!--  -->
```

How can I shortcut comments next to tags in BBedit or is this not possible?  I do see that <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly crude Applescript to do what you want

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    find ">" searching in text 1 of text document 1 options {search mode:grep, starting at top:false, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false} with selecting match
    select insertion point after selection
    set insertionP to selection
    set text of insertionP to "<!-- <##> -->" & (text of insertionP)
    select insertion point before selection
end tell
```

At the end it will position your cursor at the end of your tag. Pressing TAB will jump to the middle of your comments (the `<##>`), or of course you could ignore it and delete the comment :)